# Tokennize a sentence and re join result in Python

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have come to an issue and I'm looking for help, I do have the following code:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

d = {'col1': ['AI is our friend and it has been friendly', 'AI and human have always been friendly']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

sample_lst = []
for q in df['col1']:

   nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(q)
   for w in nltk_tokens:
          sample_lst.append(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, pos='v'))
          print(sample_lst)
```

the code works and appends wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize in the list, however, I would like to save the result in the CSV file right next to the original input like this

```
Col1                                        Col2
AI is our friend and it has been friendly   IA be our friend and it have be friendly
AI and humans have always been friendly     AI and humans have always be friendly
```

I was trying to do a  ''.join() but the result is not what I'm expecting, any thoughts on how can I rejoin the sentence and add it in the new column thanks in advance.

Comment: Shameless plug: take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#create list for all values
out = []
for q in df['col1']:
   #create list for each value
   sample_lst = []
   nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(q)
   for w in nltk_tokens:
          sample_lst.append(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, pos='v'))
   #join lists by space
   out.append(' '.join(sample_lst))

df['Col2'] = out
print (df)
                                        col1  \
0  AI is our friend and it has been friendly   
1     AI and human have always been friendly   

                                       Col2  
0  AI be our friend and it have be friendly  
1      AI and human have always be friendly
```

Another solution with nested list comprehension:

```
df['Col2'] = [' '.join(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, pos='v') 
              for w in nltk.word_tokenize(q)) 
              for q in df['col1']]
```